# Is it possible to avoid repeating the type multiple times by using Self to define associated constants?

Tags: rust, self

Using associated constants in Rust, is it possible to avoid repeating the type multiple times in the

```
pub struct MyLongNamedSpecialFlag(pub u32);
impl MyLongNamedSpecialFlag {
    pub const SOME_CONST: MyLongNamedSpecialFlag = MyLongNamedSpecialFlag(1234);
    pub const ANOTHER_CONST: MyLongNamedSpecialFlag = MyLongNamedSpecialFlag(4321);
}
```

To avoid tedious repetition, Is it possible to do something like this?

```
pub struct MyLongNamedSpecialFlag(pub u32);
impl MyLongNamedSpecialFlag {
    pub const SOME_CONST: Self = Self(1234);
    pub const ANOTHER_CONST: Self = Self(4321);
}
```

---

Trying this I get an error:

```
error[E0423]: expected function, found self type `Self`
 --> src/main.rs:3:34
  |
3 |     pub const SOME_CONST: Self = Self(1234);
  |                                  ^^^^ did you mean `Self { /* fields */ }`?

error[E0423]: expected function, found self type `Self`
 --> src/main.rs:4:37
  |
4 |     pub const ANOTHER_CONST: Self = Self(4321);
  |                                     ^^^^ did you mean `Self { /* fields */ }`?
```

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. Rust won't accept that, doesn't seem to be a clear reason why not. Addtionally, if you try to use a type alias (`type Flag = MyLongNamedSpecialFlag;`, it will give the same error: `did you mean `Flag { /* fields */ }`?`.

Comment: For some reason, you can initialize normal structs (`struct A {...}`) with type aliases (including `Self`), but it doesn't work with tuple structs. This is not specific to associated const.

Answer (score 1):

Even though it wasn't designed for this, [the `duplicate` crate](https://crates.io/crates/duplicate) can be used to achieve a little bit of what you are looking for:

```
use duplicate::duplicate;
pub struct MyLongNamedSpecialFlag(pub u32);

#[duplicate(name; [MyLongNamedSpecialFlag])]
impl name{
    pub const SOME_CONST: name= name(1234);
    pub const ANOTHER_CONST: name= name(4321);
}
```

This will expand to your exact implementation. Why?

`duplicate` is designed to duplicate whatever item it is applied to and substitutes the identifiers it is given with various code for each duplicate. In my example, it will substitute any `struct_name` with `MyLongNamedSpecialFlag`. Had we given the macro another `[...]` block, it would have made 2 copies of the whole implement. However, since we just gave it 1 substitution it simply acts as a way to reuse `MyLongNamedSpecialFlag`.

---

**Update**: As of [`duplicate` v0.3.0](https://crates.io/crates/duplicate/0.3.0) there is first-class support for the above hack:

```rust
use duplicate::duplicate;
pub struct MyLongNamedSpecialFlag(pub u32);

#[duplicate(name [MyLongNamedSpecialFlag])]
impl name{
    pub const SOME_CONST: name= name(1234);
    pub const ANOTHER_CONST: name= name(4321);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works as-is [since Rust 1.32](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-1320-2019-01-17):

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyLongNamedSpecialFlag(u32);

impl MyLongNamedSpecialFlag {
    const SOME_CONST: Self = Self(1234);
    const ANOTHER_CONST: Self = Self(4321);
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", MyLongNamedSpecialFlag::SOME_CONST);
    println!("{:?}", MyLongNamedSpecialFlag::ANOTHER_CONST);
}
```